# OP non-answer is accepted and actual answer is not accepted anymore

Tags: discussion, self-answer, unaccepted-answer

Possibly I'm just being annoying, so feel free to remove this.

I answered to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37964748/autofac-property-inject-issues/37965616) some time ago and the answer was accepted.

Yesterday the OP made a sort of comment to my answer, and marked it as the accepted answer, so I got a -15.

It's not a real nuisance, or a major problem, but I feel just a little bit upset.

Should I do something, other than rant here?

Comment: The acceptance is 100% the OP's prerogative. You can't do anything about it. If your answer is better, it`ll get upvoted more, and if you have 2 upvotes more than the accepted answer, you are getting more rep out of this

Comment: The OP's answer is not a non-answer.  It is an answer.  It's an answer that's less detailed and less in depth, but it *is* an answer.

Comment: Well, I'm seeing it now. The point is: where should I ask how to behave on the main site? I thought I could ask here in the most plain way I could think of.

Comment: @A.Chiesa: Your question is on-topic for meta. The downvotes here are probably due to disagreement.

Comment: @A.Chiesa: Ranting is never an option. You have to keep your feelings out of it. If you would have explained the behavior in question in an objective tone and asked whether it conforms to our etiquette or not, then your post might have been better received.

Comment: Sometimes people screw you over, either intetionally or by accident. Not sure which this was, but man, that was painful.

Comment: @honk: well, I don't think my question was a "proper" rant. I used the term and the expression "It's not a real nuisance, or a major problem, but I feel just a little bit upset." to address the fact that I wanted to know if this situation has to be expected or what. I'm perfectly fine with the answer of Glorfindel, which is exactly what I wanted to know. It seemed appropriate to ask here about this kind of situation, which happens quite commonly.

Comment: @A.Chiesa the question is 100% on topic here. It is a duplicate though, so maybe it shouldn't have been posted without checking for dupes first

Comment: @A.Chiesa: Don't get me wrong: I feel with you and I didn't down-vote. I also don't think that you overacted here. I just tried to come up with an explanation for the down-votes. Maybe you should have omitted sentence 1 and 4 and reworded sentence 5 to not contain the word "rant".

Comment: Hmm.. is it okay to mark a question as a duplicate of a question that is already marked a duplicate of another question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope, the decision on which answer to accept is **entirely** up to the OP - not even moderators can interfere with this decision. On the plus-side, as this is an accepted *self*-answer, your answer will stay on top of it and attract the most attention (as long as it has the best score).

<sub>P.S. this action cost the OP 2 reputation points - accepting *somebody else's* answer gives you +2 points, so unaccepting it and accepting your own is a -2.</sub>